# PHP & Mysql select from big data

Tags: php, mysql

My database have 10.000.000 record

I want select from database but it is heavy

**Query** i have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` USE INDEX (id) JOIN `new` AS p1 
USE INDEX (pid) ON table.id = p1.pid 
WHERE `p1.date` > '2015-02-01' AND `p1.date` < '2016-02-01'
```

Comment: what does heavy mean? what is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ......` ? what is the table structure? please provide some more details

Comment: this select it takes time

Comment: Does your second `USE INDEX (id)` need to be `USE INDEX (pid)`

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake

Comment: show the indexes you have on `table`

Comment: have you created indexes on the table or not?  SHOW INDEX FROM mydb.mytable;

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on columns `new.date` and `table.id`.

You probably don't need the USE INDEX hints.

I am assuming that there not too many rows in the date range. If a large proportion of your rows are in that range, obviously, it will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

use

> "LIKE" instead of "="

Comment: Add some explanation to this answer